# Reading MSMQ messages with Java Library on Unix machine?

Tags: java, linux, unix, jms, msmq

I am looking for a java library that can handle MSMQ incoming messages on a Unix machine.

When searching the web for a solution a found almost nothing, and the few I did found are accessing MSMQ on windows OS.
In my case, my application is running on Unix and I want to transfer MSMQ messages directly to it from a Windows machine.

I guess I need some kind of a bride/listener/receiver for that.
The closest thing I could find was a service that offers a full solution and not a development tool.

Is there something out there that I missed which will serve my purpose?
what is the effort of writing it on my own? Is this even doable?